# qgis won't `apt-get upgrade`

Tags: ubuntu, qgis-3, apt-get

I'm trying to upgrade QGIS to the latest (3.0.3) under Lubuntu 18.04 LTS. However, the `apt-get upgrade` stopped working:

```
$sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libqgis-customwidgets python-qgis python-qgis-common qgis qgis-common
  qgis-plugin-grass qgis-plugin-grass-common qgis-provider-grass
  qgis-providers qgis-providers-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
```

I checked that nothing is kept back with `sudo apt-mark showhold`.

However, the `install` command:

```
sudo apt-get install qgis
```

seems upgrade qgis to the latest version without an issue. The entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
deb https://qgis.org/debian bionic main
```

Any idea what could be preventing the `upgrade` from working? (And is it safe to force the upgrade with `install`?)

Comment: have you done `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: Then try `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` - this happens if the packages to upgrade require packages that you don't have yet. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38837/what-does-the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-mean/241062#241062

Comment: I think the issue is this: 3.0 and above only available with ubuntugis (plain xenial lacks GDAL2) - meaning you'll have to hook up to the ubuntugis repository to get v3.0 on your version of Ubuntu...

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, I did `sudo apt-ge update` first. After that, `upgrade` didn't work but `install` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short is the repository has change/moved/added a dependency.  You current installation of qgis has a package it needs to install new but it isn't going to install it as a part of the upgrade, so puts a 'soft hold' on qgis.  This way Debian will leave you with a out of date but working qgis installation.

If you reinstall qgis, as you pointed out, it will succeed.

https://debian-administration.org/article/69/Some_upgrades_show_packages_being_kept_back

The best-practice is to `install` not `dist-upgrade`, this could mess up your system depending on its current state.

https://askubuntu.com/a/602/75295